# Correct way to configure caddy, S3, and CloudFront

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My ultimate goal is having Caddy, Django, S3, and CloudFront with best practice setup.

The problem is `Chrome` is not execute font from `S3`, but `css` it does
Here is the console errors

> Access to Font at
>   'https://herr.s3.amazonaws.com/static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff'
>   from origin 'https://herr.reviews' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://herr.reviews' is therefore not allowed
>   access.
>
> Access to Font at
>   'https://herr.s3.amazonaws.com/static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff'
>   from origin 'https://herr.reviews' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://herr.reviews' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I am doubt. If my configuration is wrong. 
Why `css` comes to the browser?

`CaddyFile`

```
www.{$DOMAIN_NAME} {
    redir https://herr.reviews
}

{$DOMAIN_NAME} {
    proxy / django:5000 {
        header_upstream Host {host}
        header_upstream X-Real-IP {remote}
        header_upstream X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}
    }
    log stdout
    errors stdout
    gzip
}
```

I confirm I can upload and download `media` file from `S3`
`CaddyFile` is a default setup form `django-cookies-cutter`

**Question:**
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hey there I know this is an old post, but I just ran into almost this exact same config issue on a rails app. I wrote an article about it on [Medium](https://medium.com/@levinology/legalverses-move-to-caddy-aws-ecs-cloudfront-and-our-cors-problem-bc0b0cccfc00).

Cloudfront is caching the response from your web server. Direct files are no problem, however, you most likely have a css file that is requesting that font and your browser is making a secondary request. So the css file, which is now loaded from a different origin(your CDN) now is requesting to load the font, thus the CORS error.

You need to include a header in the response from Caddy that says which origins are okay to grab that file when serving files in that directory. Cloudfront will then cache that response and you'll resolve the CORS error.

This example is based on config for Caddy 2, but the concept is the same.

First, we create a matcher called @assets. That matcher will match any request to $DOMAIN_NAME with a path of /assets/.

Then we specify 2 headers, one to allow any origin and another to specify the types of request that are allowed (get/post).

```
 @assets{
    host $DOMAIN_NAME
    path /assets/
  }

  header @assets Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  header @assets Access-Control-Allow-Methods “GET, POST”
```

Since you're only serving from a single name and no other subdomains, you don't need the extra host matcher and you can also lockdown the origin to just your $DOMAIN_NAME.

Here's a slightly simpler alternative snippet that should do the same thing.

```
header /assets/ Access-Control-Allow-Origin "$DOMAIN_NAME"
header @assets Access-Control-Allow-Methods “GET, POST”
```

Put either snippet inside of your host block and you're off to the races.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine because `font` is hard-coded in Django template. If direct file like `css, javascript, and media` is working. No problem.

In the Django production. People get Django admin page from other technique. For example ssh and tunneling to database and then `runserver` from localhost